# How can I render complex json in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have object nav in my rails application. But the nav obj will have another nav obj.

My question is, how can i output or render json like this that nav have another sub nav and may have unlimited depth? Many thanks!!!

```
"nav": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Home",
                "icon": "home",
                "nav": [{  id: 2,
                           name: "game"
                           icon: 'game'
                           etc.......

  }],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jbuider is the solution for complex json.

Check the great tutorials for complex json (jbuider) -

1) [jbuider Asciicast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?view=asciicast)

2) [jbuider customized Json](http://blog.crowdint.com/2012/08/24/using-jbuilder-to-customize-json-objects.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use tools such as [Jbuilder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder), [Rabl](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl), ...